# How do I make sure all these constructors are called?

Tags: c#, constructor-overloading, constructor-chaining

This is about c# constructors and has been asked before a couple of times. However, the questions and answers never really fit my scenario:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

    public List<int> MyIntegers { get; set; }

    public BaseClass()
    {
        this.MyIntegers = new List<int>();
    }
    public BaseClass(int initialInteger) : this()
    {
        this.MyIntegers.Add(initialInteger);
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public List<string> MyStrings { get; set; }

    public DerivedClass()
    {
        this.MyStrings = new List<string>();    // does never get initialized
    }
    public DerivedClass(int initialInteger) : base(initialInteger)
    {
        this.MyStrings.Add(initialInteger.ToString()); <-- exception because DerivedClass() is never called
    }
}

// In Program.cs (or where ever)
var derivedClass = new DerivedClass(10);
```

The code above will fail because the parameterless constructor of `DerivedClass` is never called. So, `List<string> MyStrings` is not initialized.

I know I can't do constructor chaining with base() and this() at the same time. But of course I could do this:

```
// Workaround      
public DerivedClass(int initialInteger) : base(initialInteger)
{
   this.MyStrings = new List<string>(); // redundant
   this.MyStrings.Add(initialInteger.ToString());
}
```

This works, but it's pretty ugly because I am using redundant code. It seems ok here in the simple sample, but in my real application I would have to add a lot of redundant code. Not nice.

How would you solve this elegantly?

Comment: `public List<int> MyIntegers { get; set; } = new List<int>();`?

Comment: @Kirk: Sorry, not sure how your suggestion solves my problem. MyIntegers in BaseClass is fine. It's the MyStrings part in the DerivedClass that causes problems.

Comment: How can it be redundant? A redundant thing can be removed with no ill effect. It might be "repeating yourself" but that doesn't mean it's redundant. Kirk typo'd btw `public List<string> MyStrings { get; set; } = new();` - one statment to init the list regardless of which constructor is called

Comment: @Caius: Well, this.MyStrings = new List<string>(); is "redundant" if I use it as in my workaround.

Comment: In this simple context I would just initialize the list in its own declaration. In more complex scenarios I would create a private Initialize() method common to both constructors

Comment: @Caius: Agreed. It's not redundant. it is repeating my self. But that clarification does not really solve my problem. The sample above is pretty simple. In my real application all constructors have more stuff to do than just initializing a list. That's why I need to make sure all relevant constructors are executed.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, a separate Init(). This is what I was thinking too. I was just hoping for something that is more elegant though.

Comment: What's inelegant about it?

Comment: @Caius: Haha. Good question. It just looks ugly to me if I had to call Init() from within every relevant constructor. In my real application I have many constructors and I guess I was hoping for a solution that is more like "chaining".

Comment: So.. diff between `Constructor(..) : base(..)` and `Constructor(..) { Init(..)`?  - "call INit in every relevant constructor" - it's only like "call base/this in every relevant constructor" ?

Comment: @Ingmar you can do the same thing for your subclass.  It was an example.

Comment: @Kirk: Ok, sure. But in my real application there is a little more to do than initializing lists. So I really need a constructor (or Init method). But thx for your help!

Comment: Also, would default values for constructor parameters help, as an alternative to overloading?

Comment: @Caius: Sorry, I didnt understand your last post. All I can say: Constructor(..) : base(..) or Constructor(..) : this(..) loks elegant to me. Constructor1(..) : base(..) { Init(...); ... }, Constructor2(..) : base(..) { Init(...); ... } etc. does not.

Comment: @Caius: Unfortunately no. I am already using default parameters as far as possible. The scenario above is for all such parameters where I have no defaults.

Comment: @All: Thanks guys. I give up ;) Obviously I have to go the "hard way" of adding Init() to every single one of the relevant constructors. This is ok. I just wanted to make sure I don't miss the obvious. Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: I think in this case you could reduce both the constructors to a single one taking `params int[] initialValues` and then it can construct the lists via `ToList` from LINQ. Of course, you could also hide that constructor and keep separate constructors as your public interface if you really wanted to.

Comment: @Damien: Yep. This would work in my simple sample. But not in my real world ;) Thank you though for the good idea.

Comment: The fact that you have many (?) constructors make me think if it is better to have also a class to pass for the initialization. Something like _SettingsForYourClassName_ and then you could look at the properties set in the instance passed to decide what to do and reduce the number of constructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, a constructor with few parameter should delegate to one with more parameters, ideally having one single constructor that does all the actual initialization.

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

    public List<int> MyIntegers { get; set; }

    public BaseClass() : this(new List<int>())    {    }
    public BaseClass(int initialInteger) : this(new List<int>(){initialInteger}) {   }
    protected BaseClass(List<int> myIntegers) => MyIntegers = myIntegers;
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public List<string> MyStrings { get; set; }
    public DerivedClass () : this(new List<string>(), new List<int>())    {    }
    public DerivedClass (int initialInteger) : this(new List<string>(){initialInteger},new List<int>(){initialInteger}) {   }
    protected DerivedClass (List<string> myStrings, List<int> myIntegers) : base(myIntegers) => MyStrings = myStrings;
}
```

The downside with this is that some initialization-logic is duplicated, i.e. the derived class needs to create a list of integers to give to the base-class. If your creation logic is to complicated it might hint that your model is problematic, or that you should extract some of the creation logic to a separate factory class. Another tool that might be useful is an inversion of control container.

This assumes the given problem is a placeholder for something else, since this specific problem could easily be solved by just taking a `params int[] initialValues` as Damien_The_Unbeliever suggest in the comments.